# Looking for Docker Image octopusdeploy/octo for Apple M1

Tags: docker, arm64, octopus-deploy

I'm running Docker Desktop for Mac (v4.4.2), part of the deployment script of the company, it needs to use octopus and the Docker image for it is not available for the Apple M1 platform according to the error message:

```
Unable to find image 'octopusdeploy/octo:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from octopusdeploy/octo
/usr/bin/docker: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries.
```

I've also tried to manually download the latest image and manually update the tag to match 'octopusdeploy/octo:latest' but encountered many other issues, most importantly, the build artifact was not what our devops engineer expected.
I understand there is no straight answer to this as it's not officially supported. Any pointers for direction is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is [the source code](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusCLI/tree/master/Dockerfiles) for the octo [docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/octopusdeploy/octo/tags), they dont have any tags matching with linux/arm64/v8, so you might have to build your self ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusCLI/blob/master/Dockerfiles/alpine/Dockerfile)) and publish somewhere.